# Can't move a link(shaped into a block) to center

Tags: html, css

I just want to move the 3 links(shaped into block) to center. it should be easy but I just can't figure out how to. Center as in horizontally center. its probably a silly mistake or concept problem. I don't want to move the text in centre of box, just want to move the box.
CSS:

```
<style> 

*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
header li{
    list-style: none;
}

a:link, a:visited
{                            
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: green;
 border: 5px solid black;
 color: white;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 width: 200px;
position: relative;
margin-left: 240px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a:hover, a:active{
    color: black;
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 1.5em;          
}

header li:nth-child(3)
{
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header>
    <ul> 

        <li><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"> Google</a></li> <!-- notice here how when 9i add "http:// the link will open and if don't it won't-->
        <li><a href="www.facebook.com" target="_blank"> Facebook </a></li>
        <li><a href="www.wikipedia.com" target="_blank"> Wikipedia </a></li> 
    </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about displaying your whole unordered list as an inline block and centering the text content within your header, making the list centered:

```
header{
    text-align: center;
}

header > ul{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWvXQg)

*Note: I removed the margin from your anchors, since I assumed this was some attempt at making them more central. Correct me if I'm wrong.*

Comment: Works, thanks so much.
But can you explain? Because I was not particularly looking for the correct version I just want to know where I was going wrong conceptually and what is "inline-block" doing?
Why this doesn't work?
ul{ text-align:center;}

Comment: @Akshit `inline-block` elements behave fundamentally like `inline` elements as far as the page flow goes. Adding `text-align: center` to your header pushes the inline (and hence inline-block) content to the middle of the element. `text-align` doesn't affect the alignment of block elements, which is why your attempt didn't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Sorry to ask this out of context but can you suggest me some source/anything to learn Web development from? I feel what I'm learning now is not enough and i'm way too poor at this at the moment.

Comment: Some of the best and most popular are http://css-tricks.com/ and http://www.html5rocks.com/ -- Nobody learns this stuff overnight. Everybody starts off 'poor', they just need practice.

Comment: Thank you. they don't seem to have video tutorials though. where did you learn it from?

Comment: A little bit of everywhere. Reading never hurt anyone ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also add `margin: 0 auto;` to the actual anchor tags and remove your `margin-left` attribute.  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1tLkbhby/1/)

Comment: Thanks buddy, can you please explain though? I was just playing with it, not particularly looking for correction, I want to know where I went wrong conceptually and also why doesn't this work ul{text-align:center;} since I'm moving the list in center here.

Answer (score 0):

As it's been said, to center blocks horizontally you should use automatic margins on both left and right sides. It will work with any block (not inline elements) that has a specified width. Inline elements can easily be converted into blocks with display: block;

```css
div{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;


  
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```